# Do I have legal rights against a company that offered me a raise to not leave, and then promptly fired me after turning down another offer?

Tags: job-offer, united-states, termination, legal

I was just informed of this situation that occurred somewhere by a co-worker, and was wondering what the legal ramifications are (U.S. Law). To be clear, the scenario is as follows:

- I tell my boss I've been offered a position at another company.
- My boss later comes to me with a counter offer of a raise, if I choose to stay with them
- I accept the counter offer, and inform the other company that I have chosen to stay with my current employer
- After a week, my boss then informs me that I'm being let go, and that this should serve as a lesson to not mess with him.

For the above scenario, regarding U.S. law, do I hold any legal grounds against this? What options would I have to defend myself (and my family) from being blatantly told that I was fired because I was willing to accept another offer without some other counter-offer from my current employer?

As for the chap this *did* happen to, I'm informed that he contacted the company who originally gave him the offer, and they were still willing to bring him on-board. So, yay (somewhat) happy ending to an otherwise terrifying situation.

Comment: This depends highly on location.  In the US in an at will employment then its in general completely legal to fire some one for any reason or no reason at all.  (general since there are some anti discrimination laws out there that vary by location).  Although since this question is specifically legal its off topic for this site.

Comment: Legal questions are out of scope for this SE site. Voting to close

Comment: Legal questions are off-topic here at the Workplace. However, I think this would be a good fit over at the [Law SE](http://law.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I've re-asked my question there: http://law.stackexchange.com/questions/5139/do-i-have-legal-rights-against-a-company-that-offered-me-a-raise-to-not-leave-a

Comment: I would tell HR and other employees.  That is just plain vindictive.

Comment: While US is an at will employment mess in most states, if you have proof of this statement "After a week, my boss then informs me that I'm being let go, and that this should serve as a lesson to not mess with him." you could have a case. You can talk to a lawyer about it.

Comment: This is a good example of why it is not a good idea to get a raise by threatening to leave. As awful as the manager was for terminating employment, he actually _was_ being messed with.

Comment: @teego1967: As presented by the OP, it was the employer who offered the raise. It seems the employee was planning to leave for the new job. In a case such as this, he (the employer) was the one "messing with" the employee.

Comment: @teego1967 - Not at all true. If someone is leaving purely for financial stability, and of no contempt for the position they're in, asking for a raise prior to leaving is absolutely not messing with anyone. It's expressing a _desire_ to stay, but perhaps not the _financial ability_ to do so.

Comment: @MrDuk, I'm not absolving the employer of awful behavior, but if one is going to leave it is best to just leave. The story as given here seems like the guy was just trying to "strong arm" the boss for a raise by threatening to leave. A better approach would have been to leave or to ask for a raise and go to the new job if the raise was denied.

Comment: The best course of action is to **name the company** so that others know who it is. This won't help you now but may help prevent similar incidents like this in the future.

Comment: Even in the US in a state with at will employment, there are probably laws against this kind of retaliatory action.

Comment: Lesson: **Decide where you want to work, and that do that!** Don´t try to play out your employers against each other, it will always affect your reputation even if they don´t react in such a poor way!

Comment: When you talk to a lawyer, also assume this may not be a labor law thing. He may have the right generally to fire you, but he actually caused damage - there are separate laws for this. A good lawyer may look at different angles.